# How can i combine two nested selectors in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

I'm writing styles for my button the following way:

```
.btn {
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, $red 50%, $red-dark 50%);

  &-small {
    background: $red;
  }

  &-blue {
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, $blue 50%, $blue-dark 50%);
  }
}
```

How can i write a selector for the small blue button to only include the $blue background, not the gradient, without writing out the selector names like `&.btn-small.btn-blue`?

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
@mixin background-gradient($color1, $color2) {
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, $color1 50%, $color2 50%);
    &-small {
        background: $color1;
    }
}
.btn-red { @include background-gradient($red, $red-dark) }
.btn-blue { @include background-gradient($blue, $blue-dark) }
```

2)

```
.btn {
    &-red {
        background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, $red 50%, $red-dark 50%);
        &-small {
            background: $red;
        }
    }
    &-blue {
        background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, $blue 50%, $blue-dark 50%);
        &-small {
            background: $blue;
        }
    }
}
```

same resoult:

```
.btn-red {
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, red 50%, red 50%);
}
.btn-red-small {
    background: red;
}

.btn-blue {
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, blue 50%, blue 50%);
}
.btn-blue-small {
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i think my question was a bit confusing. I want my class atrribute to look like this: "btn btn-small btn-blue"